# Keeping location hash after a tag redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static website, that translates the data, based on location hash `(window.location.hash ==="#en")`

Not so long ago, it was just one page site, but now there's a couple more pages. When the `a tag` redirects to other page, the location hash dissapears. Is there a way to keep the hash all the time after a language selection at the end of the url after redirections?

Comment: Probably, but it would be a pain to maintain and very easily broken. A better approach would be to store the user's language setting in a cookie/localstorage so that the URL doesn't matter at all.

Comment: You could also 1. Add `window.location.hash` to all your links. 2. I haven't tried it but you probably can use `window.navigation.addEventListener('navigate', () => { /** Add the hash */}` 3. Add the user language to your url like `website.com/en/posts/1`

Answer (score 0):

It probably is as said, but you need to think about why you need it and how you going to manage it.

You could store the language coming from hash to have less work and end up with a function like that:

```
const getLocation = (language?: string | null): string => {
  const hash = window.location.hash;
  const location = localStorage.getItem("location");

  language = language ?? hash ?? location;

  if (language) {
    localStorage.setItem("location", language);
    return language;
  }

  if (hash) return getLocation(hash);

  if (location) return getLocation(location);

  // Default location if no hash or location is set
  return getLocation("#en");
};

const actualLocation = getLocation();
```

Whenever the hash was in place, your localStorage will be updated and available across pages.